# Prevent collapsingToolbar from expanding for certain fragments

Tags: android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, appbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to prevent a `CollapsingToolbar` from expanding for one of my fragments.

Currently, when I use the method `setExpanded()`, I am able to see the toolbar in its collapsed state.

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
```

However, the collapsingToolbar is still expandable, which is not what I want. I want the collapsingToolbar to not be expandable for this particular fragment.

In other words, I want the collapsingToolbar to behave and look like a regular toolbar (i.e. "not expandable") for this particular fragment only.

I am using [Mike Penz's Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). The code below shows the relevant code, with notes indicating what I have tried.

```java
private void buildDrawer(){
    Drawer drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withFullscreen(true)
            .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(accountHeader)
            .addDrawerItems(
                item1,
                item2,
                new DividerDrawerItem(),
                item3,
                item4
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Fragment f = new Fragment();
                    switch (position) {
                        //other cases not shown                            
                        case 2:
                            f = new LocateFragment();
                            appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
                            //Adding the following three lines don't work - causes the toolbar to be unscrollable, but in its expanded form
                            //AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)collapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                            //p.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP); 
                            //collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
                            //toolbar.setCollapsible(false); doesn't work either
                            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Locate Events");

                            setInvisibleAddPhotoFab();
                            break;
                        //other cases not shown 
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragments, f);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return false; //close drawer onclick
                }
            })
            .build();

    loadBackdrop();
}
```

This is what I want - I want the toolbar to be unexpandable:

[image]

Currently, however, it is still expandable, so the image below is NOT what I want:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I was able to collapse the toolbar and prevent it from expanding like so (code below), but I've run into another issue - the title no longer appears on the collapsingToolbar when I set it like so: `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("string");`

```java
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
int px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = px;
appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: will you explain what is the `80` in the px code line, cuz it gives me with the line of px initialization, `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: project...n, PID: 24890
                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment xFragment{ffd3ec0} not attached to Activity
                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:646)
                                         at project....Fragment.<init>`

Comment: @DasserBasyouni It sounds you're having a different issue with the fragment not being attached to the activity. Try searching for `not attached to Activity` e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262994/asyctask-throwing-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem using the following (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746806/4383320) by @DanielPersson):

```java
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);  
toolbar.setTitle(title);
```